# Spring Security: Converting OAuth2AuthenticationToken to custom token

Tags: java, spring, security, oauth

I have a Spring Boot App in which I'm integrating OAuth as the authentication method. However for authorisation I use a proprietary and custom library which has its own logic on fetching permissions and so on.

I have it working in that a user can log themselves in via OAuth and the library works correctly fetching relevant user data and so on.

My only problem is that this library can also be used to authenticate users. For this it uses a `CustomToken` which is based on a `JaasAuthenticationToken`. If logging in via OAuth the authentication is of type `OAuth2AuthenticationToken`.

My question is can I somehow somewhere in the authentication workflow "exchange" the `OAuth2AuthenticationToken` for a `CustomToken`? I can't post any code so I hope this is enough to get an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question because I have solved it.

With `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(new CustomToken())` I can set the authentication. Initially I ran into a problem because I did that step in a `GrantedAuthoritiesMapper` (because thats where I manually logged in the user with the legacy library and then added the authorities to my OAuth authentication) and apparently somewhere later in the authentication workflow the authentication gets set again.

So instead I created and set the `CustomToken` in a AuthenticationSuccessHandler and now it works as intended.